# Access My Cloud Home files from Raspberry Pi

Tags: cloud, nas

It is possible to access WD My Cloud Home files from Raspberry Pi, since it seems there is no WD My Cloud Home desktop app for Raspbian?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

There is no WD My cloud home application for linux. This said, My cloud home is also accessible by the SMB protocol (v2 or v3). Consequently it would be a public share. It is handy if you don't need to protect it. The WD discovery app on Windows and Mac are for private space shares on the mycloud home meaning that noone else that the owner can see its content on the mycloud home.

On the other hand, everyone can access the Mycloud home SMB space share.